# Icons as titles with fl_chart?

Tags: fl-chart

I'm creating a simple bar chart with `fl_chart` (below) and need to use icons as x titles (rather than text). E.g., replace `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` below with icons.

[image]

Below is the code that generates the current bar chart. Is it possible to add icons/PNGs as titles? `getBottomTitles` returns `SideTitles` which can only be a String?

```
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'bar_data.dart';
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'bar_data.dart';


class BarChartWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double barWidth = 50;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => BarChart(
    BarChartData(
      alignment: BarChartAlignment.center,
      maxY: 20,
      minY: 0,
      groupsSpace: 30,
      borderData: FlBorderData(show: false),
      barTouchData: BarTouchData(
        enabled: true,
        touchTooltipData: BarTouchTooltipData(
          tooltipBgColor: Colors.white,
          tooltipRoundedRadius: 8,
        )
      ),
      titlesData: FlTitlesData(
        topTitles: BarTitles.getTopBottomTitles(),
        bottomTitles: BarTitles.getTopBottomTitles(),
        leftTitles: BarTitles.getSideTitles(),
        rightTitles: BarTitles.getSideTitles(),
      ),
      gridData: FlGridData(
        drawHorizontalLine: false,
      ),
      barGroups: BarData.barData
          .map(
            (data) => BarChartGroupData(
              x: data.id,
              showingTooltipIndicators: [0],
              barRods: [
                BarChartRodData(
                  y: data.y,
                  width: barWidth,
                  colors: [data.color],
                  borderRadius: data.y > 0
                      ? const BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(6),
                        )
                      : const BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(6),
                        ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, very nice chart :).

Then, this is the response from the creator of fl_chart:

> Hi. At the moment there is no possibility to support Widgets in the
> title. (I hope we can implement it in the future)
>
> As a workaround, you can have an icon font to implement icons instead
> of texsts.
> https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/issues/880